# addEventListener() not working more than once. Pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to do a code challenge with pure Javascript, but the function on the addEventListener is working only once. I've tried to look for the possible answer searching on the web, but apparently something is not working.

Here is my code!

```
var btn = document.getElementById("next");

btn.addEventListener("click", clickDelay);

function clickDelay(){
document.getElementById("testing").classList.add("mystyle");
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("testing").classList.add("new-style");
}, 1000); }
```

SASS here

```
.mystyle
animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite

.new-style
animation-play-state: paused
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: Well your event listener just adds a couple of classes. Once a class has been added, adding it again does nothing...

Comment: How you get that "addEventListener() not working more than once" ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the class `mystyle` **when the element is already a member of that class** will have no effect.

You should change your logic so that:

- The `animation` property is set on the element *by default* (i.e. without needing a class to be added by JS).
- The `animation-play-state` is set to `paused` on the element (also by default as above).
- Adding the class with JS changes the `animation-play-state` to `running`
- The function you passes to `setTimeout` **removes** that class (which sets the `animation-play-state` back to `paused`.

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I've tried that and now the problem is that the animated background goes back to the original position, instead of stopping where I need. I'll continue looking for a solution!